# c++ Realy large floating point calculation

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer

I want to do really large floating point calculations. Should be fast enough.

How can I make use of Graphics processors if available? If not GPU available then I would like to use main CPU.

thanks

Comment: By large means number digits - digits should be scalable.  For example Largest prime number 2 ^ (43112609-1) digits.

Comment: This is way to general. Please could you be more focussed.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the number of significant digits? Or are you really talking about [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), where the number of digits are limited only to the available computer memory?

Comment: I suggest you start by using something that attempts the calculations - say http://www.mpfr.org/ - and see if that's fast enough.  No point worrying about performance when you've presumably (given the vagueness of the question) got no real idea how long these calculations might take: you could easily end up with nothing working at the end of the day, or something that takes .2 seconds but took months to build when 2 seconds would have been fine and taken a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the 'size' of these numbers, you can try [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), although its not a GPU solution, it can handle big numbers and should be relitively fast, its used by a few opensource compilers(GCC & LLVM) to do static constant folding, so its designed to preserve accuracy.

To do work on a GPU (really a [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)), you'd need to write a kernel using soemthing like [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [DirectCompute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectCompute), and do your number crunching in that.

You may also be interested in intels new [AVX extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point calculations can handle very large numbers, very small numbers, and numbers somewhere in-between.  The problem is that the number of significant digits is limited, and and number that doesn't perfectly fit in a base two representation (numbers similar to 1/3 or 1/7) will experience errors as they are translated into their closest base 2 counterparts.

If a GPU is available, as one is in nearly all computers with video, then a libarary like GPGPU should help you access it without writing tons of assembly language.  That said, until you are sure your computations will involve operations that are similar to those already performed by a GPU, you would be better off avoiding the GPU as they are excellent for doing what they already do, and poor at being adaptable to anything else.